# jQuery setting height on document load problem

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem setting height after the document is loaded heres code pieces:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var oldHeight = $('.gallery-block').css('height');
        var newHeight = oldHeight + 100; --> was for testing
        $('.gallery-block').css('height', '+=100');
    });
</script>

.gallery-block
{
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

the document loads with the same width, i need it to load with height value + 100 without setting it in the css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work as you have it.. `$('.gallery-block').css('height', '+=100');`
`

This functionality, though, was added in v1.6 and above..

Alternatively you can use

```
$('.gallery-block').css({height:'+=100'});
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Qe7WV/

---

For pre-v1.6 versions (*if you are not allowed to upgrade for some reason*) you can use animate with 0 duration.

```
$('.gallery-block').animate({height:'+=100'}, 0);
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Qe7WV/1/

**or**

use the version that accepts a function as parameter (*v1.4 and after*)

```
$('.gallery-block').css('height', function(index,value){ return parseInt(value)+100; });
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Qe7WV/2/

Comment: it wont change the height value is the same

Comment: if im loading the value from another place first like: height: <%=someplace.Height %>;  does it effect the process of on document load?

Comment: perfect bro i think i was using pre 1.6 version worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example using .height instead: http://jsfiddle.net/Akkuma/qRZQb/